# Install iphone development apps remotely

Tags: iphone, applet, app-store

Is there a way to install iphone apps in development stage (not distribution) remotely? can I send the user the binary and install the app via itunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called "ad hoc distribution". You need an ad-hoc development profile and need to register the UUIDs of the phones on which you want to install the app. Then it's installed through iTunes.